# Fetching memcache variable on each request causing problems

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE memcache to fetch a boolean on each request. This boolean is a flag to enable/disable a particular url.

If its true, everything works as normal, if its false then it sends back a particular format response.

The service is servicing about 7 requests per second, and the problem is Google seems to have introduced limits on accessing memcache and now this fetch is failing consistently at around 1 request per second since a few days ago, so this process has become totally unreliable. I've had to do an emergency patch remove this check from the code. But I need an alternative routine to enable/disable the service.

Using a servlet instance variable is an option, but each jvm instance will have their own so it can't work.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: That doesn't sound good!  What is the simplest request you can have that still exhibits the problem?  What if your entire request consisted of just getting that memcache value.  Does the problem still happen?  What runtime are you using, and what does your memcache call look like?

Comment: Are any warnings about your app present in the admin console while/after this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limits (other than sanity checks) on how often you can access memcache. In any case, though, you should never rely solely on memcache to store a value; you should always have a fallback to a permanent storage mechanism such as datastore.

Answer (score 0):

To hold consistency, it may be a better idea to use datastore/transaction instead of memcache.

To reduce the latency of datastore/transaction, you may try to mix memcache and datastore/transaction methods. For example

```
# while reading status 
# 1. try to read from memcache
# 2. if memcache exists, return the value
# 3. if not, read from datastore, save to memcache, and return

# while writing status
# 1. use a transaction to write data to datastore and memcache
```

Comment: This is already how it works. The boolean memcache value is backed up by the datastore if it doesn't exist already, just as you stated.

It isn't as if the value is not in memcache returning a null, it actually fails to fetch it from memcache and throws an exception. This has been working fine, and never happened before until about 2 days ago.

If I re-fetch on that memcache exception that occurs it will simply be too expensive as it'll happens way too often.